# Git push failed. error: RPC failed; result=56, HTTP code = 0

Tags: git, bitbucket

I use bitbucket repository and I made a lot of changes in the project.
So when i push into rep, i got an error. SourceTree : git -c diff.mnemonicprefix=false -c core.quotepath=false push -v --tags origin Develop:Develop
POST git-receive-pack (23013447 bytes)

fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly

error: RPC failed; result=56, HTTP code = 0

Pushing to [bitbucket](https://DenisMD@bitbucket.org/DenisMD/radixmanager.git).
Everything up-to-date

Completed with errors, see above.

I tried:

```
git config --global http.postBuffer2M

git config http.postBuffer 524288000
```

but it doesn't help.

Comment: Also i have ADSL wireless router.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The error from what I know means that the upload link got terminated in a way that it wasn't supposed to.  This is typically because of either a timeout or network connectivity issues.  With increasing the buffer size the servers shouldn't be timing out, but you may still have other issues to check for as below.  Note that I am assuming that you have a space between http.postBuffer and 2M in "git config --global http.postBuffer 2M" since your original post didn't and I thought it is a typo when entering it here.  You could also change the global buffer to a much larger size like by using 524288000 (which is 500MB) instead of 2M (i.e. git config --global http.postBuffer 524288000)

A few other things:

- If you have a software firewall like Kaspersky AV, disable it and retry.
- If you are over wireless connection, switch to a hardwire ethernet.  Some wireless adaptors/drivers seem to be problematic with large commits.
- Make sure you have a reliable ISP link.
- Also if you are using HTTP for git, setup SSH key-pair and use them instead.

Comment: Ok , i will try. I used SSH, but it does not help.

Comment: how to solved this at last?@DenisMarkov. them not wark for me.

Comment: push with -u key helped me.