# git push failed The remote end hung up unexpectedly

Tags: git, bitbucket, git-push

```
error: RPC failed; result=56, HTTP code = 0
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
Everything up-to-date
```

Just started getting this error today morning when
trying to do a git push and it won't work. Other repos are good to go but not this one.
Git pull works. I am on Ubuntu if that helps.

Also tried this and it doesn't work either

```
git config --global http.postBuffer 524288000
```

Comment: Check your remote URLs: `git remote -v`

Comment: What are the results of `git fetch --all --prune`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Git push failed. error: RPC failed; result=56, HTTP code = 0](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29557504/git-push-failed-error-rpc-failed-result-56-http-code-0)

Comment: I have noticed that whenever 
{{Writing objects: 100% (28/28), 980.20 KiB | 0 bytes/s, done.}}
whenever the writing object passes 300 Kib it wont push.
Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was one project folder that had photos which I had to remove.
It took me a whole week+ to figure out since the project is under 100mb

Answer (score 1):

It can also be due to the file names containing special characters.

After 5 days of struggle, today I figured out that some files contain "%, @, ~, +" and this error "fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly" is so non intuitive.

The whole magic of a universal iOS project is based on ~ and @, the file names have format "myImage~ipad@2x.png"
If you try commiting such project from terminal you can observe "writing objects xx%" and then it breaks.

relevant ref : https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/CONFSERVER-4503